# Как вызвать метод в другом классе?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public class TimePickerClass  extends AppActivity{

public TimePicker mTimePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_picker_class);
    Button saveTimeButton;
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    saveTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    saveTimeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        getTime();
    });
}
 public String getTime(){
    //TODO
    int hour;
    int minute;
    hour = mTimePicker.getHour();
    minute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
    String message;
    message = "Time:" + hour +" : " + minute;
    return message;
}
```

}

Привет! У меня есть класс в котором с помощью TimePicker я получаю выбранное юзером время. Как мне в другом классе получить это время?
я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
TimePickerClass time = new TimePickerClass();
String userTime = time.getTime();
```

Но это не работает, приложение падает. Как тогда это реализовать?
Ошибка состоит в следующем:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.gfc.glanceclock, PID: 32256
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TimePicker.getHour()' on a null object reference
```

Соответственно, если поменять вызов getHour() и getMinute() местами, упадет при getMinute()

Comment: Как именно падает? Покажите код ошибки

Comment: Изменен вопрос. Добавлена ошибка

Comment: А где вы инициализируете `mTimePicker` ? Похоже, что пока нигде

Comment: Я создаю его в TimePickerActivity и нахожу его id. Что-то нужно еще сделать в другом классе?

Comment: Вы создаете объект класса `TimePickerClass`, но в конструкторе `mTimePicker` не инициализируется. Возможно вам надо вызывать метод `onCreate` перед `getTime` ?

Comment: Нет, не помогло то, что я поменяла методы местами

Comment: Ошибка у вас в том, что переменная `mTimePicker` не инициализированна. Но без полного кода дальше - это гадание на кофейной гуще.
Найдите, где у вас присваивается значение этой переменной и разберитесь, почему оно не присваивается

Comment: Это весь код,что имеется. Если добавить обычный Toast в самом классе TimePickerClass. то время определится правильно. Мой вопрос как раз и состоит в том, что я не знаю, как получить это время в другом классе!

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `public TimePicker mTimePicker;` на `public TimePicker mTimePicker = new TimePicker();`

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor "TimePicker()" . Закинут в параметр getApplicationContext(). Не ругается

Comment: Ошибка все равно не исчезает

Comment: Не видя реализацию `AppActivity` и `TimePicker`  я похоже больше не могу ничем вам помочь. Попытайтесь вникнуть в то, что делает ваш код. И найдите, как инициализировать добавленную вами переменную